# Update UILabel from another class

Tags: ios, class, delegates, uilabel, nsnotificationcenter

I was looking for something that solve my problem, but I didn't find anything usefull.
Some code:
`ClassA.h`

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : UIViewController
{
   ClassB *clsB;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel  *label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) ClassB *clsB;
```

`ClassA.m`

```
@implamentation ClassA
@synthesize label, clsB;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   ...
   clsB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
   label.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", clsB.var];
   ...
}
```

The problem is that `var` is changing (I check this in ClassB implementation with NSLog) but those changes don't affect the `label.text`.

I've already tried to import `ClassA` in `ClassB` too, but this didn't work (import error) either. I've heard something about notification center but I've never used it before.

So, is there another way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: You can bypass the import error by forward declaring `ClassB` : `@class ClassB;` above your `ClassA` interface, and not importing `ClassB.h` in `ClassA.h` and instead in `ClassA.m`

Comment: Take a look at this link. It has explanations of different ways of observing / notifying: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html

Comment: @Canopus I'll take a look on this site, it'll be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Just use delegates. In class B, declare a protocol so it can send callbacks to class A!

```
@protocol ClassBProtocol
-(void)classB:(ClassB*)b valueChanged:(float)value;
@end
```

Also declare a property for class B to have a delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ClassBProtocol>delegate;
```

Remember to synthesize that delegate in your .m

Then inside class B, call the method whenever the value changes:

```
-(void)methodThatChangesValue {
    //here the value will be set
    if( self.delegate != nil ) [self.delegate classB:self valueChanged:value];
}
```

Now in class A, when you alloc/init class B, set its delegate to class A. Make sure class A conforms to class B protocol:

```
@implementation ClassA () <ClassBProtocol>
@end
...
-(void)viewDidLoad: {
    self.classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    self.classB.delegate = self;
}
```

Now just implement the delegate method of B!

```
-(void)classB:(ClassB*)b valueChanged:(float)value {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value];
}
```

Basically what happens is class A owns class B. Now we don't want class B to have a strong reference to class A, because we get a retain cycle and a memory leak. So instead, we declare a delegate of class B, which will allow it to have a weak reference to the class who owns it. So class A becomes the delegate of class B here.

Because of this, whenever the value inside B changes, we can just call the protocol method, which is implemented in class A, because it is the delegate of class B and must implement the delegate methods. Through this mechanism, you can pass values back and forth :)

Comment: I'll try to implement like you said after. It seems that is the correct way to do what I was looking for.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the import error by forward declaring `ClassB` :

```
@class ClassB;
```

above your `ClassA` interface, and not importing `ClassB.h` in `ClassA.h` and instead in `ClassA.m`

The reason a forward declare is enough is simply that all the compiler needs to know at that point is that `ClassB` is, in fact, a thing you have defined somewhere.  It is up to the linker to find that definition and hook it up.  The reason you then `#import "ClassB.h"` in `ClassA.m` is because you need to know more about `ClassB` than it simply exists in the implementation.  In this case, you need to know that `ClassB` has a property named `var`